# Need to select 2 letters with RegExp

Tags: php, regex

The thing is I have a string like this:

> iata_code@name@city@gmt_offset@country_id@iso_code@latitude@longitude@air_**os**@air_**lx**@air_**lh**@air_**sn**@air_**nz**@air_**su**@air_**s7**@air_**a3**

The marked symbols are need to be selected with regexp. It would be great if someone smart will be so kind to help me :)

I was able to write only:

```
/(@air_)\w+/g
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This lookbehind regex should work:

```
(?<=air_).{2}
```

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wQ4kW0)